# How to name the frequency of digital signal?

Tags: frequency, digital-communications, terminology

Let's imagine that we have some MCU in which each GPIO pin can be set high or low with a single assembler instruction (BSET/BCLR for example). If we divide one by the instruction execution time we get some frequency.

- This frequency is not the **sample rate** because there is no analog signal which can be sampled.
- It's not the **Nyquist frequency** because of the same reason.
- It's not the **clock frequency** because some MCUs can execute this instruction in one clock cycle and on other MCUs it takes four clock cycles.
- It's not quite the **bandwidth** because there is no specified protocol to describe what the transfered data is. I meen the start/stop bits in the UART are ... bits. But they are not data.
- It may be the **bit rate**. But on the one hand, this term also is used to describe an analog signal (such as audio or video, for example .wav). On the other hand, the measurement unit of the bit rate is similar to the bandwidth.

So what should this frequency be called? Is there any ISO/IEC or other standard which names and defines this term?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133761/discussion-on-question-by-arseniy-how-to-name-the-frequency-of-digital-signal).

Answer (score 3):

*"Let's imagine that we have some MCU in which each GPIO pin can be set high or low with a single assembler instruction (BSET/BCLR for example). If we divide one by the instruction execution time we get some frequency...So what should this frequency be called?"*

You're generating a waveform in software on an MCU GPIO pin output.

This waveform is named and given units for its application i.e. what the waveform is used for.

It is not named for the method of generating it unless that differentiates it or clarifies it in some necessary way.

For example:

- if a GPIO drives an LED with a fixed frequency to flash it, its waveform is a flash frequency in Hz
- if a GPIO driver a watchdog timer with a pulse to clear it at varying times, its waveform is a pulse with no units

It is good policy to name signals for their actual function, in specifications, on schematics, in software, in HDL etc.

Comment: And if we explore the GPIO itself? For example if we know that each GPIO pins can work at 1MHz frequency we can calculate that this MCU can theoretically: make a PWM on 10kHz with descreet of duty cycle equal 1%, transmitte data by UART with bandwidth 100kByte/sec, or emmit a 0,1usec impulse. Similar characteristic (like the maximum GPIO frequency) can be attached not only to a MCU but to a CPLD or a level shifter or even to some transmission lines. But if you call this characteristic "the frequency" a wiseman immediately appears and will accuse you of an incorrect collection of terms.

Comment: @Arseniy, no, that's not how it works, and no they won't appear and say that. I've never had that nor seen it happen over a great deal of board schematics, software and HDL for a lot of clients, not once. Please give specific and very concise examples of 'accusing'/etc happening.

Comment: A quick example that looks similar is:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/488542/what-is-the-maximum-frequency-of-cmos-level-triangle-wave

Give me some time and I will find more delicious examples.

Comment: @Arseniy, don't waste anyone's time doing so, it all looks a bit ridiculous. You have your answers. Note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum and you seem to be pursuing the latter. A specific question gets specific answers. The question and answers aren't your openers for an endless series of 'what if' chats on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's the 'Arseniy Frequency', or the 'Arseniy Clock'. Generally, you name a signal for what it's going to be used for, not how it was made (generally!). Failing that, you find some other characteristic that prompts your memory. In the absence of your telling us what it's going to be used for, then 'Arseniy Rate' is as good as any other.

Comment: There is a common term such as voltage. It does't matter we're talking about DC voltage or VRMS or pick-to-pick voltage the voltage is a potentials difference. Then if we talkin about pick-to-pick voltage for example we understand what it is even if we don't know is the signal square or sin or something else. So good terminology allows us to move between levels of abstraction. I whant to understand is there any term general enough not to go into details every time and that would not provoke self-proclaimed wisemen to self-presentation. Because the frequency term does it.

Answer (score 1):

Central frequency will be up to 0.5/execution time, bandwidth will be up to 1/execution time as signal differs more from a periodic one.

So, if clock is 10 MHz and execution time is 1 clock tick, and signal is 0101010... Then central frequency is 5 MHz and bandwidth is 0 Hz, excluding jitter and harmonics.

If clock is 10 MHz and signal is random, then central frequency is 5 MHz, and bandwidth is 10 MHz, from 0 Hz to 10 MHz.

Technical term for the second type of signal is [ultra-wideband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-wideband)

If bits are repeated, like this: 001100110011... you can obtain lower central frequency, 2.5 MHz in this case with 0 bandwidth. And you can select a wider bandwidth by adding noise. This make it possible to [synthesise any frequency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing) up to a limit.

In total, method you are offering allows to create a complex signal with properties that depend on the pattern you use to switch the state of the transmitter.

With very sensitive receiver you can push bitrate up to a bandwidth with this setup. But bitrate assumes errors to be corrected, which is unlikely in this setup. So bitrate will be lower, proportional to data loss. Relation between these terms are described in article about [baud](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud).

There is no specific term that you are looking for. But your idea can be described using simpler terms, that althrough dont fit exactly, still give some information about your idea.

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Generally I call it the "toggle time", rather than invert it to a frequency